# Can't purge Snap package

Tags: libreoffice, snap

When entering

```
sudo snap --purge libreoffice
```

I'm getting error: `unknown flag`purge'`

Answer (score 12):

The `--purge` option is used in addition to the `remove` command. To remove a snap without saving a snapshot of it's data use:

```
sudo snap remove --purge libreoffice
```

Please take a look at `man snap` or [online](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/snap.8.html) to see which commands and options can be used with `snap`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no purge command for snaps.

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```